# How upload photo in database CI

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm have question about how upload photo in database CI, before, i done searching how upload photo but not success.

**This is controller**

```
 tambah_aksi()
{


    $this->load->library('upload');
    $nmfile = "".time(); //nama file saya beri nama langsung dan diikuti fungsi time
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/barang/uploads/'; //path folder
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp'; //type yang dapat diakses bisa anda sesuaikan
    $config['max_size'] = '3072'; //maksimum besar file 3M
    $config['max_width']  = '5000'; //lebar maksimum 5000 px
    $config['max_height']  = '5000'; //tinggi maksimu 5000 px
    $config['file_name'] = $nmfile; //nama yang terupload nantinya

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if($_FILES['filefoto']['name'])
    {
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('filefoto'))
        {
            $gbr = $this->upload->data();
            $data = array(           
            'id_barang'         => $this->input->post('id_barang'),
            'nama_barang'       => $this->input->post('nama_barang'),
            'stock_barang'      => $this->input->post('stock_barang'),
            'harga_barang'      => $this->input->post('harga_barang'),
            'ukuran_barang'     => $this->input->post('ukuran_barang'),
            'gambar'            => $gbr['file_name']   
            );
            $this->barang_model->tambah_data($data); //akses model untuk menyimpan ke database

            //pesan yang muncul jika berhasil diupload pada session flashdata
            $this->session->set_flashdata("pesan", "<div class=\"col-md-12\"><div class=\"alert alert-success\" id=\"alert\">Insert data berhasil !!</div></div>");
            redirect('barang'); //jika berhasil maka akan ditampilkan view upload
        }else{
            //pesan yang muncul jika terdapat error dimasukkan pada session flashdata
            $this->session->set_flashdata("pesan", "<div class=\"col-md-12\"><div class=\"alert alert-danger\" id=\"alert\">Insert data gagal !!</div></div>");
            redirect('barang/tambah'); //jika gagal maka akan ditampilkan form upload
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$nmfile = "file".time().".png"; //nama file saya beri nama langsung dan diikuti fungsi time
$config['upload_path'] = '/uploads/'; //path folder
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp'; //type yang dapat diakses bisa anda sesuaikan
$config['max_size'] = '3072'; //maksimum besar file 3M
$config['max_width']  = '5000'; //lebar maksimum 5000 px
$config['max_height']  = '5000'; //tinggi maksimu 5000 px
$config['file_name'] = $nmfile;

$this->load->library('upload');

if ($this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $gbr = $this->upload->data();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($gbr);
        echo exit;
```

then check upload directory.

Comment: thankyou ,that solved my problem !

Comment: Thanks for mark answer as right please give it a upvote.

Answer (score 0):

you can use $this->upload->display_errors() show the error

Answer (score 0):

**Step I - Create Views:** 
First Setup the Codeigniter `base_url()` function and then go to **application>>views** folder. In views folder of Codeigniter 3, you can see the file - **welcome_message.php**, edit this file and Create an Image Upload form. You can also copy and paste the below code to create an image upload form.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Upload Image Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Welcome/image_upload/' , array('id' => 'img'));?>
  <h3>Image Upload Form</h3>
  <input type="file" name="pic" tabindex="2" required>
  <input type="text" name="alt" placeholder="Image Alt Text" tabindex="1" required>
  <button type="submit" id="img-submit" data-submit="Sending">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also add some CSS codes to Design the form.

**Step II - Create Database and Image Upload Folder:** 
Now create a folder in your project  where images will be uploaded and create a table - 'image_upload' in your project database from phpmyadmin, you can also copy and paste the below code to create a table :

```
CREATE TABLE `image_upload` (
`image_url` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`alt` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

**Step III - Controller:** 
Now go to application>>Controller, there will be a PHP file called 'Welcome.php'. First, you need to add form and URL helper and load the database like below:

```
public function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->database();
  $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->helper('form');
}
```

Now create an image upload function in your Controller as bellow:

```
function do_upload()
{
  $url = "../images";
  $image=basename($_FILES['pic']['name']);
  $image=str_replace(' ','|',$image);
  $type = explode(".",$image);
  $type = $type[count($type)-1];
  if (in_array($type,array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif')))
  {
    $tmppath="images/".uniqid(rand()).".".$type; // uniqid(rand()) function generates unique random number.
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]))
    {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'],$tmppath);
      return $tmppath; // returns the url of uploaded image.
    }
  }
  else
  {
    redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/Welcome/not_img', 'refresh');// redirect to show file type not support message
  }
}
```

The function `do_upload` is uploading the selected image from the form of **welcome_message.php** into the folder, you have created in Step-II and returns the image URL.

Now we will save the URL of uploaded image into MySQL database.See the below code:

```
function image_upload()
{
  $data ['image_url']= $this->do_upload();
  $data ['alt']= $this->input->post('alt');
  $this->db->insert('image_upload', $data);
  redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/Welcome/', 'refresh');// Redirect to Success page
}
```

The function `image_upload` will save the image URL on your database.You can view the uploaded images by using below code:

```
<?php
  $images = $this->db->get('image_upload')->result_array();
  foreach($images as $row):
?>
  <img src="<?php echo base_url().$row['image_url'];?>" class="img" alt="" />
<?
  endforeach;
?>
```

So these are the simple steps to upload an image using Codeigniter 3 and save in MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

use $this->upload->display_errors()

Answer (score 0):

1. First in views directory create a view and add a form.

   **View File**

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>

    <head>

    <title>Codeigniter Upload Example</title>

     </head>

    <body>

   <?php echo $error; ?>

    <h3>Upload Example</h3>

    <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/upload_file'); ?>

     <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

      <br /><br />

      <input type="submit" value="upload" />

        </form>

       </body>
   ```
2. **Create a folder** for storing uploaded files e.g (**photos**)
3. Next **Create a controller** like this:

**Upload Controller**

```
 class Upload extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('upload', array('error' => ' ' ));
        }

        public function upload_file()
        {
                $config['upload_path']          = './photos/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|doc';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
                {

                    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');

                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('upload', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('someview', $data);
                }
        }
}
```

**View Uploaded file information.**

After uploading image to some directory you can create another view file and assign uploaded data and can use file information.

```
<?php foreach ($upload_data as $item => $value): ?>

<p><?php echo $item;?>: <?php echo $value;?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Uploaded file**

```
  <img src="<?php echo base_url().'/uploads/'.$upload_data['file_name']; ?>" />
```

**Saving to database**

You can use above image information and pass, image name, path and related information to you query

Hope this code help you. You can find a detail tutorial on how to upload a file using codeigniter here. [Codeigniter file upload example](https://programmerblog.net/codeigniter-file-upload-example/).